# Connect to an image of an Amazon EC2 instance without SSH

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon EC2 instance (redhat 8.6)

I can create an image of that instance using the process described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html ,
with the purpose of loading the image on another server.

Amazon EC2 access by default is using ssh with private key.

I need to allow shell access to the instance without ssh. Just a simple user+password.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: A Guess: Either enable it before exporting or if you have console on it after importing it.   In both cases you sould probably modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config and   add the following line: PasswordAuthentication yes.